# Output to terminal different than I redirect output to file AND output to terminal

Tags: file, unix, terminal, output, stdout

So for some reason when I run my script and have it output to the terminal just as it would, I get my intended output. Yet when I redirect the output to a file, I don't receive full output.

Let's say I have an executable named "filename" and run it "./filename", the output on the terminal is, let's say :

```
a
b
c
```

Yet if I do "./filename > output.txt" or "./filename |& tee output.txt", the output on the terminal AND the output.txt text file is just, let's say:

```
a
b
```

I know this isn't very specific, but my output is huge. I was thinking this would be general enough to provide general solutions/ possible problems.
I'm using a program someone else made, so I don't know where this additional output is called. Yet, it shouldn't matter since the functionality of the program doesn't change, just what's being output.

Comment: I know it’s possible, go check how the WeAllContribute does that on GitHub (that’s the only package I know that does that)

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal code sample to reproduce, it's very hard to guess what's going on.

But some things you could try:

- Redirect *all* output streams to your file, i.e. `your-script &> output.txt`
- Run it through `strace` and look for `write` and `open` calls to see what's going on
- Read and debug the source code to figure out what's going on